# How to convert lat lng to a Location variable?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making a map app in android, I want to get 2 locations on the map, and see the distance between them. I already got my current location as a "Location" variable. The other place however is saved as two variables : double lat,lng;

I have checked the internet and found this method that will help :

```
float distance = myLocation.distanceTo(temp);
```

The problem is that the "temp" I have is not a "Location", it is 2 different doubles.

Is there a way to convert them to Location?

PS. Code i tried but did't work :

```
Location temp = null;
temp.setLatitude(23.5678);
temp.setLongitude(34.456);
float distance = location.distanceTo(temp);
```

Problem :

> Null pointer access: The variable temp can only be null at this location

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to instantiate `Location`, before accessing its members. For example

### Java

```java
Location temp = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
temp.setLatitude(23.5678);
temp.setLongitude(34.456);
float distance = location.distanceTo(temp);
```

### Kotlin

```
val distance = location.distanceTo(Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).apply {
    latitude = 23.5678
    longitude = 34.456
})
```

Comment: Lol, this is one Kotlin > Java illustration.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can get the distance without instantiating a Location object at all using the static method [Location.distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)).

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(1, 2, 2 , 2, results);
```

> **public static void distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double**
> **startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[]**
> **results)**
>
> The computed distance is stored in results[0]. If results has length 2
> or greater, the initial bearing is stored in results[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)). If results
> has length 3 or greater, the final bearing is stored in results[2].
>
> Parameters
>
> **startLatitude** the starting latitude
>
> **startLongitude**    the starting longitude
>
> **endLatitude**   the ending latitude
>
> **endLongitude**  the ending longitude
>
> **results**   an array of floats to hold the results

Comment: This method is interesting and will help much too !